# Sharing a ListView across multiple TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf

I've started working on a project and am using WPF for the first time. I am typing up the XAML and viewing the render result and I've come across a re usability issue.

I have a tab control with three tabs. Each tab will contain a list view. Each list view will be identical in terms of layout/structure but will hold different states of data. Here is what it looks like currently:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header = "Green">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header1" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header2" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header3" Width="100"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Amber">

    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Red">

    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

In the Amber and red tabs I am unsure whether I need to just copy and paste what is located in the green tab or if there is a better way of doing this that allows me to reuse the list view XAML easily in three places?

**EDIT: After reviewing the answer provided by Andy combined with some additional research I have used the following solution**

```
<Window.Resources>
        <GridView x:Shared="False" x:Key="BaseListView">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header1" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header2" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header3" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header4" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header5" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header6" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header7" Width="100" />
        </GridView>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button ToolTip="Upload HSBC Spreadsheet file">
                    <Image Source="/Resources/Buttons/UploadButton.png" Height="32" Width="32"></Image>
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header = "Green">
                <ListView View="{DynamicResource BaseListView}">
                </ListView>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Amber">
                <ListView View="{DynamicResource BaseListView}">
                </ListView>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Red">
                <ListView View="{DynamicResource BaseListView}">
                </ListView>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of actual resource usage, you can't get the lists to share a common view but you could style up the view so you only need to create it once.

Take note of the x:Shared attribute here, this means a new instance of the view will be created for each ListView.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListView" x:Shared="False">
            <Setter Property="View">
                <Setter.Value>
                     <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Header1" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Header2" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Header3" Width="100"/>
                    </GridView>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header = "Green">
            <ListView>
            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Amber">
            <ListView>

            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Red">
            <ListView>
            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting and the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way is to put the ListView in another Usercontrol and set the ListView ItemSource to the UserControl DataContext, and Use the UserControl in all the three tabs, So that you just need to set the dataContext for the UserControls to the particular collections based on Tabs